# abi-decoder's decodeMethod returns undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, abi

I am trying to decode the input field of [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xef5e380bb647ffeb4e87321ad4a73c4d06bbf23ff116ac3ad79d80df0ce8dc44) transaction as below,

`const decodedInput = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(transaction.input);`

but decodedInput returns `undefined` despite the my ABI having the entry for swap (as below - taken from the contract's ABI in Etherscan)!

```
  {
    inputs: [
      {
        components: [
          {
            internalType: 'address',
            name: 'tokenAddress',
            type: 'address',
          },
          {
            internalType: 'uint256',
            name: 'amountIn',
            type: 'uint256',
          },
          {
            internalType: 'address',
            name: 'receiver',
            type: 'address',
          },
          {
            internalType: 'bytes',
            name: 'permit',
            type: 'bytes',
          },
        ],
        internalType: 'struct OdosRouter.inputToken[]',
        name: 'inputs',
        type: 'tuple[]',
      },
      {
        components: [
          {
            internalType: 'address',
            name: 'tokenAddress',
            type: 'address',
          },
          {
            internalType: 'uint256',
            name: 'relativeValue',
            type: 'uint256',
          },
          {
            internalType: 'address',
            name: 'receiver',
            type: 'address',
          },
        ],
        internalType: 'struct OdosRouter.outputToken[]',
        name: 'outputs',
        type: 'tuple[]',
      },
      {
        internalType: 'uint256',
        name: 'valueOutQuote',
        type: 'uint256',
      },
      {
        internalType: 'uint256',
        name: 'valueOutMin',
        type: 'uint256',
      },
      {
        internalType: 'address',
        name: 'executor',
        type: 'address',
      },
      {
        internalType: 'bytes',
        name: 'pathDefinition',
        type: 'bytes',
      },
    ],
    name: 'swap',
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: 'uint256[]',
        name: 'amountsOut',
        type: 'uint256[]',
      },
      {
        internalType: 'uint256',
        name: 'gasLeft',
        type: 'uint256',
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
  }
```

I've check out related links, [Abi-decoder returns undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135701/abi-decoder-returns-undefined) & [myContract.getPastEvents returns undefined event](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/88156/mycontract-getpastevents-returns-undefined-event), but they are quite different from my problem.

Comment: I think your problem is that `abi-decoder` hasn't been updated for several years. I'd suggest to look for alternatives like ethersjs or web3.js.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems related to how `abi-decoder` computes the function identifier (the hash of the function signature); in particular, it associates `swap` function to the `0x899a73f4` ID and not to the correct `0xf17a4546`.

As pointed out by Ismael, the project has been stale for a few years now, and this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Consensys/abi-decoder/issues/96), so I suggest using a more updated library to execute the decoding, i.e., [ethers.js's AbiCoder](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/abi/abi-coder).

As a workaround, if you still want to stick with `abi-decoder`, you can replace the function ID like this:

```
const decodedInput = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(transaction.input.replace('0xf17a4546','0x899a73f4'));
```